# is there any ways to select row that is between two dates?

Tags: r

i have a data with two date with is start_date and end_date
[image: reference data]

how do i select the row which is for example the month of may?

what i have tried

filter with start_date >= "05" &  end_date <= "05"

or

subset(data, format.Date(start_date, "%m") >= "05" & format.Date(end_date, "%m") <= "05")

thanks in advance, im new with R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solves the question, silly me.

```
campaign_on_may <- subset(data, format.Date(start_date, "%m") == "05" & format.Date(start_date, "%Y") == "2017")


campaign_on_may <- rbind(data, subset(campaign_descriptions, format.Date(end_date, "%m") == "05" & format.Date(start_date, "%Y") == "2017"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure R, you can use `as.numeric` with `format`.

```
subset(data, subset=as.numeric(format(start_date, "%m"))==5 & 
           as.numeric(format(end_date, "%m"))==5)

  start_date   end_date
8 2020-05-06 2020-05-26
```

---

Or using **lubridate** to reduce code:

```
library(lubridate)

subset(data, month(start_date)==5 & month(end_date)==5)

  start_date   end_date
8 2020-05-06 2020-05-26
```

Use of `as.numeric` is not really needed for that example, but suppose now you want to subset rows in which a date is *between* two months, say May and June. We can easily modify the above code with the following.

```
> subset(data, month(start_date)>=5 & month(end_date)<=6)
  start_date   end_date
8 2020-05-06 2020-05-26
9 2020-05-25 2020-06-14
```

And to incorporate the year, we just use `as.Date()` instead of `month`.

```
subset(data, start_date>=as.Date("2020-04-01") & end_date<=as.Date("2020-05-31"))
  start_date   end_date
5 2020-04-10 2020-04-30
6 2020-04-10 2020-04-30
7 2020-04-20 2020-05-10
8 2020-05-06 2020-05-26
```

---

**Data**:

```
data <- structure(list(start_date = structure(c(18311.2161748139, 18312.2842345089, 
18326.147890578, 18349.8989499761, 18362.2961949771, 18362.3596080979, 
18372.229088068, 18388.4478125423, 18407.5741012516, 18430.0561228655
), class = "Date"), end_date = structure(c(18331.2161748139, 
18332.2842345089, 18346.147890578, 18369.8989499761, 18382.2961949771, 
18382.3596080979, 18392.229088068, 18408.4478125423, 18427.5741012516, 
18450.0561228655), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

   start_date   end_date
1  2020-02-19 2020-03-10
2  2020-02-20 2020-03-11
3  2020-03-05 2020-03-25
4  2020-03-28 2020-04-17
5  2020-04-10 2020-04-30
6  2020-04-10 2020-04-30
7  2020-04-20 2020-05-10
8  2020-05-06 2020-05-26
9  2020-05-25 2020-06-14
10 2020-06-17 2020-07-07
```

Comment: will this method found the row if date is between the start_date and end_date ?

Comment: Nope. That's a totally different question to the one you asked. You asked for the month of May.